# Getting the full path of the DLLs from a PE import table

Tags: c++, import, portable-executable

I'm reading the import table of a PE file and I'm able to get the names of the DLLs it imports from the IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR structures but I can't find where the DLLs paths are.
How can I read them?

Comment: Is it an option to do this at runtime instead? It would be a lot easier.

Comment: No... I'm afraid I need to know this before the exe starts to run. :/

Comment: Must you do this manually? If it's just the paths you want, you can achieve this by running `depends` command-line: http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_command_line_help.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait until runtime to be able to get hold of the paths to imported DLLs. This is because the answer depends upon the runtime environment at the point at which the library is loaded.

For example, two different programs could have two different DLL search paths. And so the paths to the imported DLLs could be different for those two programs.

Comment: Hmmm... since I need this information just before the execution, I can "search" these paths myself for the filename, like windows does. right? :)

Comment: in theory yes but to get an exact match to the windows algorithm will be very hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, the system will load the corresponding dll from an appropriate location at runtime. it's impossible to figure out the path before that point.

Answer (score 1):

PE Images ONLY contain the names (and extension) of the dependencies NEVER their path.